# Can you share resources about implementing I2C device on FPGA?

Tags: i2c, artix-series-fpga

I am using Xilinx 7 Series and the official toolchain.
So far, I have been using a few Zynqs with moderate success but they come with ARM cores I don't use so I am attempting to move to a pure Artix.

For the time being, I'd switch to basic I2C. I think I'm not hitting the right keywords. The previous discussions here on stack exchange seem to focus on issues with existing I2C implementations or interfacing with other devices with the FPGA as a controller.

I have found quite some source code and I'd say it more or less matches my plans but: there's usually no discussion about pins, no mention about `{I,O}SERDES`, `IOBUF`, `PULLUP` or even just io constraints!

Given the low speed of I2C, I understand driving the pins directly without using the hardened serializers makes sense but at least something about timing constraints (they are fairly alien to me) would be required, would them?

I am considering just making prefboard and test a few led blinks but before I go that way, can you share some *resources about implementing an i2c **device** on FPGA*?

Comment: There is nothing special about I2C.  Well, yeah, the pins should be open-drain (and apparently `inout`) so they can be pulled down by the other side. The best "resource" would be I2C specification.

Comment: If you're using Vivado, just use one of Xilinx's I2C IP blocks.

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about @TimWescott , my IPs in Vivado are only about ~master~ / Controller, there are no devices. Besides, even AXI lite is too big for me, I need to figure out a way to make it built-in in my module.

Answer (score 1):

The business with pinning, I/O drivers/buffers and constraints is very vendor-specific compared to the actual logic. That's why IP cores usually implement the logic only and leave you to connect, drive and constrain the external signals. There are also details that are board-specific (internal or external pullups? clock/trace skew?) which IP core designers cannot know about or handle for you.

Don't be afraid, I2C is a robust and very well established and supported bus. If you jump in and run into specific issues you can certainly address them, and well- researched and targeted questions are welcome here.